# Set up site where only theme and contributed modules are under git version control

Tags: version-control

I'm working on a site for a large organization where they host a git repository for the code.  But that doesn’t include a copy of Drupal (the core).  Their repo has modules and themes directories, files directory, and a few other script files.

So for development I have another completely separate local copy of the site running.  What I’m going to run into is -

1. develop in my local code, then
2. try to remember what files I changed & copy them over to the repository..
3. add, commit & push to develop branch

Is there some magical way that I can install Drupal in a directory outside the repository, but for the theme and contributed modules, point to the directories in the repository?

This is on a Mac.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding but wouldn't a simple symlink do the trick? `ln -s /path/to/repo/modules /path/to/drupal/sites/all/modules` and the same for themes/files/etc?

Comment: Do you need to push to the central repo or just pull changes from it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files ?